# Is boost message_queue name the same as a named pipe?

Tags: c#, c++, ipc, message-queue, boost-interprocess

Nowhere is this mentioned in the docs, is the name we use for creating a `message_queue` a named pipe on Windows? Suppose a C# application creates a `NamedPipeServerStream` with name "MyPipe". Can a C++ application do IPC with it if a `message_queue` uses the same name "MyPipe"? Is this behaviour the same for all platforms? I used `message_queue` in my implementation because there's no cross platform named pipe solution in C++ afaik. Will closing the `NamedPipeServerStream` have the same effect as `message_queue::remove`?

Comment: I think if a _named pipe_ or a different OS mechanism for IPC is used, is an implementation detail.

Comment: If you want to use Windows named pipes from C++, you can also call the [Win32 C API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipes) directly.

Comment: @rveerd I don't want to mess around with Win32 api, heck I am using boost::dll for loading libraries. I want cross platform compatibility

Comment: There are [boost::process::pipe](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/process/reference.html#header.boost.process.pipe_hpp) and [boost::process:assync_pipe](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost/process/async_pipe.html)